# WCF: "IsRequired" property for DataMember with "IsReference" property for DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

Why does WCF does not allow to set the "IsRequired" property for DataMembers when I set the "IsReference" property for the DataMember's DataContract? And is there a way to solve this problem?

```
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class MyClass
    {
        private DateTime date;

        [DataMember (IsRequired = true)]
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set { date = value; }
        }
    }
```

This code will create an error because "IsReference" and "IsRequired" are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an explanation for the behaviour you're getting [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e5d38e14-31b0-4991-a988-d578c564e92d)

I'm not sure about way's to solve this issue

Comment: Whilst this is in no-way a dig/rant at yourself, the "answer" in that link does not actually explain why the framework behaves in that way, only that it is "by-design" and in typical patronising MS fashion; it doesn't explain anything about *why* they'd made that design decision, and suggests we do not worry our selves with the real reason, only that we remove the attribute and carry on regardless. </rant>.